# Apply a list of function to a parameter

Tags: ramda.js

I'm looking for something like this

```
const applicate = (functions, parameters) => {
  let result = parameters;
  for (let i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {
    result = functions[i](result);
  }
  return result;
}
```

The usage ends up with something like this :

```
applicate([fn,...], parameter)
```

with

```
const fn = (parameter) => parameter * 2

applicate([fn, fn], 2) = 8
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably `pipe` or `compose` would help here

```js
const applicate = (fns, ...args) => R.pipe(...fns)(...args);

console.log(
  applicate([
    R.add(23),
    R.multiply(3),
    R.divide(2),
  ], 100),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-buL0byPvI/XRDFscnSc/e0q+sLA65O9y+rbF+0O/4FE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

I'd suggest to not go for this custom `applicate` solution,
as you can see it just aliases what is the behaviour of pipe already...

You could try to get used to `Pipe/Compose` as they're an important piece of the fp toolbox and people are very used to such glossary alredy.

```js
const applicate = R.pipe(
  (n) => n * 2,
  (n) => n * 2,
);

console.log(
  applicate(100),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-buL0byPvI/XRDFscnSc/e0q+sLA65O9y+rbF+0O/4FE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Nice reading: https://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/05/31/thinking-in-ramda-combining-functions/ (pipeline chapter)

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get this to work in ramda.com/repl, I edited the post in case I wasn't clear enough : /

Comment: It works as intended, but i think you should remove the parameters in the list of function ([R.add, R.multiply, R.divide]) - thank you !

Comment: @cp151: Those parameters turn binary functions into unary ones with partial application.  Thus `R.multiply(2)` is similar to your `(parameter) => parameter * 2`.

Comment: @cp151 I just added one more thing around aliasing pipe, please take a look